# Sketch and find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the coordinate planes, plane x+y=4 and surface z=root(4-x)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, multiple-integral

I understand that this can be done with triple integrals, but my class has yet to be taught those and we will be assessed on our ability to perform a question similar to this one with the principles of double integrals, so, how would the volume of this solid be found using double integrals?

I was thinking of using Green's Theorem, but I could not find a way to make it work for this problem.

Maybe a line integral would work, but I do not know how to set one up in this scenario.

Comment: You are integrating over a triangular region in the $xy$ plane with vertices $(0,0),(4,0)$ and $(0,4)$ so the double integral limits are easy to find. The upper bound over that region is the function $z=\sqrt{4-x}$, so that is your integrand.

Comment: Ok, so I would just have to integrate √(4-x ) from 0 to 4 on both integrals, correct?

Comment: No, because then you would be integrating over a $4\times4$ square, not a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's interesting to write the triple integral and see how it transforms in a double one if we integrate first wrt $z$.

As the line $x+y=4$ cuts the $y$ axis at $x=4$, $x$ ranges from $0$ to $4$. Now, for a given value of $x$, $y$ ranges from $0$ to $4-x$. For each $x$ and $y$, $z$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-x}$. The volume element is $\mathbb dz\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dx$

$$V=\int_0^4\int_0^{4-x}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x}}\mathbb dz\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dx=$$

$$=\int_0^4\int_0^{4-x}\sqrt{4-x}\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dx$$

We can arrive directly to the last expression considering that the integration of the function $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{4-x}$ over some region implies vertical surfaces, the ones given by the wording and this integral is the volume enclosed by those vertical surfaces and the surface of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The free application Geogebra is an excellent tool for drawing two and three-dimensional regions. Here is a drawing of your solid.

[image: Volume of Solid]

[Geogebra link to diagram](https://ggbm.at/zqmd6wcs)